# How to create a Headless Unittest library for UWP Apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, xunit

I would like to create a headless test library for unittesting my Universal Windows Platform App. I know that Visual Studio offers a test app, but this comes with a head and executable, rather than a headless library.

Even XUnit says to create this test app which again has a head to it.

http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-uwp.html

The only alternative I have found is to use a PCL To expose some of the functionality to a standard test class, but this is really non-ideal as it limits what I can test to be non-uwp functionality.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This question might be better suited to the Stack Exchange's Software Recommendations site.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with the desktop app, the Windows Runtime App was running on the app container (an isolated process with low integrity).

The unit-test for UWP app is running on a blank UWP App (to ensure the test library is also running on the app container). Since the traditional test loader is running on a normal process, I’m afraid we cannot create a headless unit-test library for UWP app which can run on a normal process.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge.  While I was unable to test headlessly, what I did was to separate out the business logic  from classes that refenced uwp classes (e.g. Windows.).  I ensured that the business logic contained only C# standard classes (sometimes, i did have to to map some classes to more common dotnet core classes, like using a `Hashtable` for my resources instead of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources`).  The `Hashtable` became my interface for passing resources around, and I have one (admittedly untested) class that maps them back and forth.

Once I did that, i created a regular headless dotnet core unit test using  `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

The unit test project file has all the classes i wanted to test (as links) as well as the unit tests themselves. By doing things this way, I'm able to test all the business logic.  The only thing that does NOT get tested is the UWP-specific stuff (In my case its just gui code, and a few mapping classes).  You can use a variety of techniques (abstract interfaces/MVVM/delegates, etc) to ensure the callback to your GUI gets CALLED, you just can't test that very upper layer.

Its not perfect, but it does provide for testing a significant portion of your app.  If you have the GUI just for display, and put all the logic into a class that CAN be tested, it will make for a very small amount of code that is not tested.